# How can I add rows from JSON data to my table?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I retrieve a JSON file from a backend function and I need to take some values from it and put them into some inputs as values that are contained within table cells and in different rows. I need to add this dynamically based on the amount of data retrieved.

JSON

```
 [
    { "Type":"Ford", "Model":"mustang" },
    { "Type":"Dodge", "Model":"ram" }
  ]
```

HTML

```
<!-- Something like this with a different JS approach? -->
<table id="tableID">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="res[i].Type" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="res[i].Model" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="res[i].Type" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="res[i].Model" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
myMethod: function () {
            var res = this;
            fetch('/cont/func', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (data) {
                    res.type = data.Type;
                    res.model = data.Model;
                    console.log(data);
                    var html = [];
                    data.forEach(function (dats) {
                        html.push(dats.Type, dats.Model)
                    });
                    document.getElementById('tableID').innerHTML = /*???*/;
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = 
"<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="data[0].Type" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="data[0].Model" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="data[1].Type" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="data[1].Model" /></td>
</tr>"

document.getElementById('tableID').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Paul. Know of a way I could implement that without hard coding the values like that? Like, to put it into a for loop?